# Промис в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Полифил для Promise.allSettled:

```js
Promise.allSettled = function(promises) {
    return Promise.all(promises.map(p => Promise.resolve(p).then(value => ({
      state: 'fulfilled',
      value: value
    }), error => ({
      state: 'rejected',
      reason: error
    }))));
  };
  
Promise.allSettled([new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(7))]).then((a) => alert(a[0].value));
```

В Promise.resolve(p).then(value ... я ожидаю, что value будет равно p(промису), почему в итоге выводится все же число? Я думал, что должен работать только вариант p.then(value ... вместо предыдущего кода. Почему исходный вариант выполняется корректно, мы ведь из Promise.resolve(p) возращаем успешный промис со значением p, которое будет value в then?

Comment: надо было просто погуглить https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_(_Promise)

Comment: похоже проще, если вы передаете в `resolve` промис, то вам просто возвращается этот же `promise` и `then` работает уже для него

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.resolve

Comment: Кажется понял, если аргумент Promise.resolve(arg) уже промис, то этот метод возращает сам arg, не "оборачивая" его в еще один промис. Спасибо!